# Adding abstract/inheritable static constructor helper method on TypeScript class

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have an abstract API class with some base api logic for our app that I am extending in various other classes:

```js
interface Options {
  authToken?: string;
  ip?: string;
  endpointPrefix?: string;
}

abstract class AbstractApi {
  private authToken?: string;
  private ip?: string;
  private endpointPrefix?: string;

  constructor({
    ip = undefined,
    authToken = undefined,
    endpointPrefix = '',
  }: Options) {
    this.authToken = authToken;
    this.ip = ip;
    this.endpointPrefix = endpointPrefix;
  }

  protected async get() {
    // ...
  }

  protected async post() {
    // ...
  }
}
```

```
class TodosApi extends BaseApi {
  constructor() {
    super({ endpointPrefix: '/todos' });
  }

  getTodos(/* ... */) {
    this.post(/* ... */);
  }
}
```

I would like to ensure that every instance of AbstractApi has a static convenience constructor: `.new()`. e.g. `const todos = await TodosApi.new().getTodos()`.

**How would I ensure that each child has this method automatically?**

---

Some things that I have tried but that haven't worked:

```js
static create(data) {
  return new this.constructor(data);
}
```

```js
static create(data) {
  return new this(data)
}
```

Comment: have you tried `return this.constructor(data);`

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to know exactly what you mean by "haven't worked".  Do you mean you got a compiler error?  Or that it didn't work at runtime?  Or both?  Anyway, I'll try to proceed and hopefully address the problem you're facing:

Since the `this` context of static methods will be a class constructor and not a class instance, you're going to need to use `new this()` and not `new this.constructor()`.  Assuming that concrete subclasses will have different constructor argument list requirements, your static `create()` method should probably take a [rest parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters).  So at runtime you want it to look like this:

```
static create(...args) {
    return new this(...args);
}
```

Now we just need to come up with appropriate typings for that method to satisfy the compiler and produce reasonable behavior when you try to use it.  For instance methods, the obvious solution involves what's called [polymorphic `this`](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#polymorphic-this-types), where the `this` type represents "whatever the current class instance type is", even for subclasses.  Unfortunately, there is (as of TS3.7) [no analogous polymorphic `this` for static methods](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/5863).  Instead, we need to use a [workaround](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/5863#issuecomment-410887254) involving generics and a [`this` parameter](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#this-parameters):

```
static create<A extends any[], R>(this: new (...args: A) => R, ...args: A) {
    return new this(...args);
}
```

That means `create` will be called as a method on some concrete constructor type which takes some argument list `A` and produces some instance type `R`.  (You could constrain `R` to extend `AbstractApi` but it's not needed here).  Let's see if it works:

```
TodosApi.create().getTodos(); // okay
TodosApi.create("bad argument"); // error: expected 0 arguments, got 1
AbstractApi.create({}); // error: this context of create does not match
```

So your desired use works fine.  You can see that `TodosApi.create()` requires the same argument list as the `TodosApi` constructor (namely, no arguments) so you get an error if you pass it the wrong thing.  And the compiler gives you an error if you try to call `create()` directly on `AbstractApi`, since `create()` requires its `this` context to be a constructable thing and `AbstractApi` is abstract and therefore not constructable.

Does that work for you?  Hope that helps; good luck!

[Link to code](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgPIAczAPYgM7IDeAUMmcnAK5gAWAKtgNYQgD8AXMnmFKAOYBuUuWDoOXHvyHlkLACbpsoMAAUoEGMAAe47rxCDiAX2LE4AIz2IwyBABs4eAgEFLPa8-TAiwsul4AbnCQFNT0TCy6kgbS5P7AQSGiUfqGMvGJKPKKymoa2ilSpjIIuHqUCGDYUAAUJDIyosgAvMiUIHL5IBByADS+DVS0DMwgLW0dXT39DeTZSuB5mlrjAOSrM+RGnBhYZQCUPrNktMB4AHRD4aPjVyMssbOnF02too8Nz+fzuerL4z9Fn9tB8TAN-NhIJUehQ8ABPEAIZB8CBgGqHerHAD0WOQ53xAzB6SgkIg0LksIRSMU3HRR2xuPx52QhOK5G4wWASIQ6mCEAAPM5ZFpIB0CHAQHCANoAXV6yAASgA+GrPTjdADuyBqTLgUD4eE4zkOzSVivluv1huQxvps3UYEoUDGmuQzx1+L1Bv2oOMpmI9kcBAYcmweE83ggIvkLjcUA8XjttjKPAqVVqGIGMjwlHQ0Dqsg6OSB+S0nFWWKqobwq2QRh9rIGKLAIbDNSxACo8fjkB2sZnjm6aGdzjS0Z3u8y+w2ZCYwa3w15zjyIHz0edmwv0QJkDjkEw4HDiAuI8veZAagAicxwCleygAWxYYEvPt3uOgJKgnCjefJyAABgofVH2fPB5T4SFkAARmIVwrEqU8VzXQh6x3PdP2qThnmTcAoxsbAYFsc8UFDCACBAKCH2CBAaGIIA)